# Java HashMap of Vectors

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, hashtable

i'm in a situation in which i'd like to have an hash map with an Integer value as key and an array of Double as values (of which i know the length).
So i want to have something like

```
        HashMap<Integer, Double[]> hash = new HashMap<Integer, Double[]>();
```

Next i scan a ResultSet finding *key,value* for the first attribute.
At the end of this first phase i will have an hash map with some keys and for each key i will have a Double value representing a particular score.

Next i want to scan another different ResultSet with different *key,values* and i want to populate my hash with these values. 
The problem is that here i can find element for which i don't have an entry and documents for which i already have an entry.

I'd like to arrive to a situation in which for a particular key i can access all different scores.

How can i add iteratively values to those arrays? because if i use the usual `hash.put(key,value)` i have to use a Double[] as value but i want to add to the hash map different score iteratively.

I think that using a Vector can bring me some problems due to the fact that some keys can have some empty values for which they don't will be populate.

Comment: could you give an example? or some code you tried?

Comment: I want to create an hashMap of array of double so:HashMap<Integer, Double[]> hash = new HashMap<Integer, Double[]>()
But when i add an element to the hash map i don't want to add all the array (because i don't know it at the beginning) but i want to iteratively add an element to every field of the array. For example i would have something like hash.put(key,0,value[0]) where 0 is the index of the position in the array in which a want to say a particular value.then i would have something like hash.put(key,1,value) that will add in the 1st position of the array for the key that particular value.

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to use Double[]? Because using list instead would made that easier a lot.

Comment: ... or a `double[]`

Comment: Hint: never put more info in comments. Update your question instead.

Comment: and how can I put a value in a particular entry of my array if a define my hash map as  HasMap<Integer, double[]>. With put() i only can put an entire array. Sorry but i can't understand how i can achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m uncertain how well I understand your requirements. I think you may do something sort of:

```
    double[] arrayInMap = hash.get(key);
    if (arrayInMap == null) {
        hash.put(key, valuesToAdd);
    } else {
        if (arrayInMap.length != valuesToAdd.length) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Key "+ key + ": cannot add " + valuesToAdd.length
                    + " values to array of length " + arrayInMap.length);
        }
        for (int ix = 0; ix < arrayInMap.length; ix++) {
            arrayInMap[ix] += valuesToAdd[ix];
        }
    }
```

I hope you’ll at least be able to use it as inspiration.

Comment: Yeah I didn't think to do this way. I'll try it thank you very much!!